# Why some notifications are not shown on iPhone (iOS 11)?

Tags: ios, notifications

We have an app that send notifications to our users. In some case, on iPhone notification we sent are not shown in the Notification Center. A user needs to open our app to see it. It starts working again if you restart your phone and make a clean install. After sending few notifications, the OS starts blocking them again. Why? How iOS is managing notifications? When does it decide to show them to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 11 some Notification Center delegates were gone (deprecated).

So you have to handle the Notification Center delegate methods to receive.

1. didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken
2. didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo
3. willPresent notification